# A formula for vector valued measurable functions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, tensor-products

Let $B_{\infty}(\Omega)$ be the space of bounded measurable functions on the  measurable space  $\Omega$. For a given Banach space $X$, let us denote $B_{\infty}(\Omega,X)$ by the set of all bounded measurable functions $f:\Omega\to X$ (meaning $f^{-1}(O)$ is measurable for every open $O$ in $X$).

> Is  the space 
>   $B_{\infty}(\Omega,X)$ just the invective tensor product of $X$ and $B_{\infty}(\Omega)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\Omega=\mathbb N$ with the disrete $\sigma$-algebra measurability is no condition and $$\ell^\infty(\mathbb N)\hat\otimes_\varepsilon X \cong C(\beta\mathbb N)\hat\otimes_\varepsilon X\cong C(\beta\mathbb N,X)$$ is (via restriction to $\mathbb N$ isomorphic to) the space of *pre-compact* sequences in $X$.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that $B_{\infty}\hat\otimes_\varepsilon X$ is always embedded into $B_{\infty}(\Omega,X)$. Right?

Comment: Yes, with respect to uniform convergence this is a closed subspace.